# What does $('<div>').parent() return?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a jQuery widget that attaches events to the widget's parent, but I'm unable to tell if it has a parent.

For example;

```
var x = $('<div>');
x.mywidget();

........... in mywidget
_create : function () {
    var y = this.element.parent() === undefined ? this.element : this.element.parent();
    y.bind(....);
}
```

I need to check if the widget has been added to the DOM before I do the bind statement. If it has not been added to the DOM, then I'll just bind `this.element.bind(....)` instead.

The problem is that `$('<div>').parent()` returns a jQuery object! I was expecting that it would return `undefined`.

So I'm wondering what parent could it be returning when it shouldn't have a parent?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/parent/  jQuery functions always return a jQuery object.  These objects may or may not contain any elements however :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `myDiv.parent().length` to know if the jQuery set is empty or not.

But this will yield false positives if the object wasn't removed from the DOM directly but it parent was.

If you want a reliable detection, then, you should use `jQuery.contains(document.documentElement, myDiv)`.

Answer (score 3):

It will **always** return an object. If you want to see whether anythings in the object, you can check for `.length == 0`, so `$("<div>").parent().length == 0` would be your check.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini LOL Welcome to the jQuery tag, fastest guns in the west ;)

Comment: @mattytommo ROFL! What about the east?

Answer (score 2):

Check the length of the jQuery object returned. If your div has no parent, the jQuery object returned by `.parent` will wrap zero elements.

Answer (score 2):

All jQuery DOM searching and manipulation methods return a jQuery collection with 0 or more elements.  `$("<div>").parent()` returns a collection with no elements (an empty collection).  You can still call any jQuery method on it, but without being tied to a DOM element what you can do is very limited.  It will have `.length` of zero, and the callback will not be reached when iterating over with `.each`.

Answer (score 2):

I would check the length of the jQuery object since jQuery will always return an object.

Answer (score 0):

it will be always a parent, can be the body for example

use jquery data for example to set your init marker

```
var wasInit = ( $(this).data("mypluginwasinit") !== undefined );
if(wasInit) return;
$(this).data("mypluginwasinit","yes");
```

Comment: The goal is to test if the element was added to the DOM. So no, it won't always have a parent.